# C/C++ in Android?

Tags: c++, c, android

Is it possible to use C/C++ code in Android?
And how easy is it?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its possible. Use the Native Development Kit (NDK). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002164/how-can-i-write-applications-in-c-or-c-for-android/1571635#1571635) for more discussion and links.

How easy is it? I don't know, I've never tried!

Comment: It's pretty easy!  All you need to do is create your classes in C++, then use JNI to launch your Native code.  One think to keep in mind, though, is that there is not a full STL implementation in Android, so you can't use things like std::vectors or std::strings.

Comment: Isn't Android used on Arm and on i386 processors?

Comment: Supported on ARM, MIPS, Power Architecture, and x86.