# How to port native c code on android

Tags: android, c

can anyone tell me how to port a native c program on android platform..should i include some c libraries or how exactly...?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution here is the start..

http://integratingstuff.com/2010/12/12/calling-native-c-code-through-jni-in-android-applications/

http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/

Answer (score 5):

Read up on the [Android Native Development Kit (NDK)](https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html)

Comment: Hi thanks Axary great answer, but 1 small doubt my c code contains the following libraries as it requires root access can i do with NDK..?#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include "fdevent.h"
#include "adb.h"

#include <linux/fb.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

Comment: @manju `unistd.h` Unix/Linux-specific, but there are alternatives (GOOGLE!)

Answer (score 1):

You may find this useful: [Using the Android NDK](http://fixnum.org/blog/2010/android_ndk/)

Answer (score 1):

I have used all those headers in one of my previous Android NDK implementations, except the mman.h and fb.h. However since mman is under sys and [fb](http://source.android.com/porting/display_drivers.html) is part of android source, I guess you should be able to go ahead with it.

Let's know what issues you come across in the process.

BTW, what calls you need from mman.h?

Comment: ok thanks for ur guidance,i will be back for any further clarification