# how to integrate c Code with Android?

Tags: android, c

I have code written in c, which contains some complex algorithms and I want to use that code in android.

I can not translate these in Android but have to include or integrate it with my Android application.

How should I proceed. please help.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656732/how-to-port-native-c-code-on-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html).