# Android NDK - write only in C/C++

Tags: java, android, c++, c, android-ndk

Is there a possible way to write a whole NDK app with C/C++ without a Java "starter" class like in hello-jni sample project (HelloJni.java) - somehow create a HelloJni.c which will do the same?

Comment: may this help you http://stackoverflow.com/q/1002164/775964

Comment: Does such library have to be in hourglass pattern or something?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since Android 2.3 (API Level 9) there is the NativeActivity which allows one to code an Android app in C++ only. There is also an example for this in the NDK package.

A quote from the [NDK Overview](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html):

> **When to Develop in Native Code**
>
> The NDK will not benefit most applications. As a developer, you need
>   to balance its benefits against its drawbacks; notably, using native
>   code ***does not result in an automatic performance increase***, but always
>   increases application complexity. In general, you should only use
>   native code if it is essential to your application, not just because
>   you prefer to program in C/C++.
>
> Typical good candidates for the NDK are self-contained, CPU-intensive
>   operations that don't allocate much memory, such as signal processing,
>   physics simulation, and so on. ***Simply re-coding a method to run in C
>   usually does not result in a large performance increase***. When
>   examining whether or not you should develop in native code, think
>   about your requirements and see if the Android framework APIs provide
>   the functionality that you need. ***The NDK can, however, can be an
>   effective way to reuse a large corpus of existing C/C++ code***.
>
> The Android framework provides two ways to use native code:
>
> - Write your application using the Android framework and use JNI to access the APIs provided by the Android NDK. This technique allows you
>     to take advantage of the convenience of the Android framework, but
>     still allows you to write native code when necessary. You can install
>     applications that use native code through the JNI on devices that run
>     Android 1.5 or later.
> - Write a native activity, which allows you to implement the lifecycle callbacks in native code. The Android SDK provides the ***NativeActivity***
>     class, which is a convenience class that notifies your native code of
>     any activity lifecycle callbacks (onCreate(), onPause(), onResume(),
>     etc). You can implement the callbacks in your native code to handle
>     these events when they occur. Applications that use native activities
>     must be run on ***Android 2.3 (API Level 9)*** or later.
>
> You cannot access features such as Services and Content Providers
>   natively, so if you want to use them or any other framework API, you
>   can still write JNI code to do so.

I would take C/C++ when porting code and possibly when developing cross platform games.

Comment: `but always increases application complexity`  Wow, citation majorly needed, android docs writer.

Answer (score 0):

Since all UI, graphics and other interesting classes are in Java you will have to use Java one way or *another*.

By *another* I mean interfacing with all Java classes through JNI. There is a library for that: https://github.com/DmitrySkiba/itoa-jnipp. Check [HelloJNIpp](https://github.com/DmitrySkiba/itoa-jnipp/blob/master/android/samples/HelloJNIpp/jni/Main.cpp) sample - it shows that it is indeed possible to write Android apps completely in C++, the only catch is that you will need to implement all needed wrappers first (some are in [samples/common](https://github.com/DmitrySkiba/itoa-jnipp/tree/master/android/samples/common) folder).

However, I recommend using Java. Its simple and elegant, has great libraries and tools.