# How slow or fast is Qt mobile for android

Tags: android, c++, qt, cordova

I would like to know the advantages and disadvantages of Qt mobile. I have heard things, like the performance is better than native apps. However I am not sure if I can trust that.

I am not a c++ developer. In fact I have no experience with c, java, c++..  I am only a web developer. I use phonegap for very simple apps. But I'd like to begin to learn new things in order to delevop better products.

Can you describe the advantages, use cases, time it takes to develop, and what Qt is in general?

Comment: [Android has a native SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1571635/1329652), so you don't need to develop in Java. Of course, Qt is native as well, so it will perform just as good as if you were using the native SDK. Qt uses the native SDK.

Comment: If you're not a C++ developer right now (and haven't even looked at Qt anywhere yet), I'd suggest starting out with using the normal Android SDK Java toolchain for developing on Android. Qt on Android is rather new and probably somewhat immature.  Basically, if you're looking to write an app for Android, use the standard way to write apps on Android unless you *know* why you should be looking at something else.  Especially when starting out on the platform.

Comment: i know more c++ than java, and i have heard that making apps in native sdk is such a pain.

Comment: from some experience with "native" Java android apps and also Qt apps on android I have to say developing good looking and performing apps is a lot faster if you know Qt and QML for the layout files. You don't even need much c++, but more JavaScript for the UI and c++ is only needed if you do some heavy stuff but I would say that is rarely the case for most apps. Just my experience with android SDK apps in java you have to do a lot of XML for the layouts and animations are a lot harder to do than using Qt I think. also you can support all major platforms with the same code.

Comment: I am actually very good with js, but total noob at c++. I know upto pointers. Do you have a blog or tutorials? it dosen't need to grammatically correct or thorough.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Native android (NDK) or Qt( based on NDK) have the same speed, but Qt saves you development time in UI, multi-Threading, Graphic, Parser, and Network programming.

For now, Qt for mobile is not working 100% as you may encounter some issues, but it is worth learning, because it works on mac windows linux ios android.  All desktop and all embedded environments.

Comment: at that moment (march 2014) there was a bugs with the camera supper slow, widget too tinny, text too small and the resize not working propelly, drawing loose the openGl context too often.

Comment: As I know, implementing Android Widget using Qt is mostly impossible.

Comment: @S.M.Mousavi, now we have Qml with javascript

Comment: @SRedouane and so can you implement Android Widget using Qt?!

Comment: @S.M.Mousavi, if you mean the one we see in the android home "like temperature widget" then i don't think so