# Can mathematical libraries like Atlas and MKL be used on smart phones?

Tags: android, ios, math, libraries, atlas

Now I want to install my own developed app on smart phones with android os or ios. Since my app will do many mathematical calculations, thus I want to use off-the-shelf math libraries like Atlas and MKL, could any one tell me whether I can use these libraries on smart phones?

Answer (score 1):

MKL seems not to be available yet:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/281168

ATLAS should build in the Android NDK (i.e., Native Development Kit)...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1046726/414125

...unless it relies on System V calls for something:

http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/faq.html#where

In general, however, you may want to architect your app to do any serious number crunching on the cloud. Android is power-optimized, so even if you succeed in installing one of these libraries, they probably will end up performing poorly and using too much power.

Comment: Very good answer! Yes, I think you are right. High power consuming maybe also the bottleneck. Thx a lot!