# How do i do Android Development entirely in C++?

Tags: android, c++

Is there any way to develop an Android app entirely using C++ without encountering Java at all? I think this question will be considered as off topic but please. Plus, I'm not asking for answers of "Why don't you just learn Java?" or "Any reason you want to avoid Java?". It's because, i don't have the patience to learn it.

Comment: A bit harsh on the sentence. But i'm really desperate for the answer/solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write applications in C or C++ for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002164/write-applications-in-c-or-c-for-android)

Comment: @nada Any helpful guides on it? I knew it before but haven't found any clear tutorials

Comment: @nada Plus, Doesn't NDK is used to link C++ with Java? I don't really understand the verbose and felt like INTENTIONAL hard structures

Comment: Sadly it's really not very straight forward as writing Android programs in Java. That's probably because of the [ART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Runtime) architecture.

Comment: To be more helpful: I once successfully followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial:-Building-SFML-for-Android) for building a C++ program for Android. SFML is a framework comparable to the more popular (but a bit lower-level) SDL mainly used for games.

Comment: @nada Funny thing about ART is that it uses a language to beat itself for another language

Comment: @nada Anyway, thank you! Hope that i could understand the tutorial